# Under what specific cases does searching for a number redirect to the question with that ID?

Tags: support, search

As you can try yourself, sometimes searching for a number redirects you directly to a question with that id: https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=129674 or https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=129093. But sometimes not: https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=13. (I will add that there is a [question with id 13](/q/13).)

What decides whether you are redirected directly to the question or whether you see search results?

In the cases when from search you are redirected, is there also a possibility do display search results (instead of going directly to the question with that id)?

Comment: funny enough [0013](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=0013) will work, but [013](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=013) not ...

Comment: Huh I didn't know search even did this. I'm not sure *why* it does this. Seems like a fairly useless feature, especially if it's not consistent.

Comment: @Martin I'm guessing there's probably a minimum threshold number. After some (incomplete) testing, it appears to be 2500.

Comment: @Sonic true. See dupe. (and it's not about number itself, just amount of digits)